# How to fix the high memory usage of fabric peer running on k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have deployed the hyperledger fabric blockchain on k8s with 3 peer nodes and 2 orderer nodes and 2 external chaincodes.

**Hyperledger Fabric v2.3.3 | Fabric-Peer v2.3**

For the peers I have **assigned resources** as:

```
resources:
        limits:
          memory: "800Mi"
          cpu: "350m"
        requests:
          memory: "750Mi"
          cpu: "300m"
```

While doing some performance testing I have noticed the following:

- The **memory usage keeps increasing** with the number of concurrent transactions, which is expected given that the messages are basically protobufs and wrapped in an envelop.
- I invoked about 500 concurrent transactions and soon the **peer pods hit the memory limit** and became unavailable which led to **multiple failures** - greylisting of peers, failure of endorsement policies etc.

Now after sometimes, when there's no more transactions in the queue, then *peer should release the memory?* But, that's not happening, the peer pod is still using the maximum memory. **Even after 1 hour the peer memory usage is maximum**

Also I have prometheus scraping all the metrics endpoints of peer and orderer nodes at an interval of 15s. And the client invokes one of the chaincode every 5 minutes (for some running total).

Are there any any environment settings which can be configured to get the optimal performance?

Answer (score 1):

What you can try to do for starters, is to disable gossip block dissemination (make [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L367) key disabled) in all peers.

Gossip keeps an in-memory cache of recent blocks used for dissemination.

Also make sure the state transfer is [disabled](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L252) and that all peers are configured to pull blocks from the orderer.

Comment: turns out to be couchdb which is using a lot of memory. i am running the peer and couchdb in the same pod, which resulted in high memory usage because of the couchdb. i have a cron job running which queries the statedb (string query). also, i am using the official hyperledger/fabric-couchdb. for 3 transactions (committed already) the couchdb memory usage is 100Mi++. is this normal for couchdb?